# Gridview SQL LIKE from Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a `textbox`, `dropdownlist` and a SQL statement bound to a gridview.

How can I add the `dropdownlist` value to the SQL statement after the `WHERE` clause?

I've try the following but it's showing no data.

```
"SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM tblPerson WHERE '" & ddlSearch.SelectedValue & "' LIKE '%" & txtSearch.Text & "%' ORDER BY FirstName
```

Comment: WARNING: [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack goes here. Especially if this will be production / live code you should read how to avoid this. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx for a starting point.

Comment: Can we have some more context? Such as: Where is the code snippet you posted placed (which event handler function?), how are the elements declared in the `.aspx` etc.

Comment: @xan Here's the .aspx `<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSearch" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="PersonID">PersonID</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="FirstName">First Name</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="LastName">Last Name</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" />`

Comment: From your markup it looks that you didn't attach any `eventhandler` on `onClick` of button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing your column name in your query so try this

```
string query = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM tblPerson
                WHERE  myDDLColumn like '% " + ddlSearch.SelectedValue + "'%'" + "and 
                myTextBoxColumn like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "'%'";
```

**EDIT** : If your dropdownlist contains the column names as value of item in dropdown then you can write it as :

```
string query = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM tblPerson WHERE "+
                ddlSearch.SelectedValue+" like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "'%'";
```

Comment: I think the ddlSearch contains the column the search term is being applied to.

Comment: @xan you may be correct but it didn't specify in question itself and here i am trying to give the idea for how to use like with variables in query to him.

Comment: @Sachin Thank you. Your suggestion worked. I was using the **&** instead of the **+** as per your code.